# Using Extension Methods with .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, extension-methods

Under Visual Studio 2008 
Can I create an Extension Method to work under a .NET Framework 2.0 project?

Comment: See [my blog ](http://colins-corner.blogspot.com/2009/01/extension-methods-in-net-20.html) entry for details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an [ugly hack](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Using-Extension-Methods-In-Fx-20-Projects.aspx) that gets Extension methods working in .Net 2.0; but it would better just to upgrade your framework to 3.5.

Alternate Sources: [1](http://www.codethinked.com/Using-Extension-Methods-in-net-20), [2](http://kohari.org/2008/04/04/extension-methods-in-net-20/).

In short (from link #2):  Extension methods are just normal static methods tagged with the [Extension] attribute. This attribute is actually just added by the compiler behind the scenes. In .NET 3.5, it lives in System.Core, so just define your own attribute like this:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
  public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. There are a few hacky methods, but the one I'm using is to take System.Core from the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/), add all of its code to a new .NET 2.0 Class Library named System.Core in my own solution, and recompile it. There are a few things to fix, like changing their MonoTODO attributes to TODO comments, and fixing the AssemblyInfo.cs, but it works great. I'm now using both LINQ and extension methods in a 2.0 project compiled in VS 2008.

Assuming you get the 2.4 version of the Mono source, you should find the code under:

```
<extracted directory>/mono-2.4/mcs/class/System.Core
```

If you're stuck in VS 2005, you can download [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/), build your System.Core dll with that targeted to 2.0, add a reference to the compiled assembly, and it may work, but I don't know if VS 2005 will have a problem with the extension syntax or not. I imagine it will give you some lip.

Comment: The key is compiled in VS 2008.  I'm still stuck with VS 2005 :(

Comment: I saw the VS2008 tag and assumed 2008. If you're in 2005, you may be able to find a pre-compiled binary, or use SharpDevelop (I'll update with a link). If you're compiling in Win2K, you're out of luck, unfortunately, since it won't support the 3.5 framework.