# Creating an extension method in a .Net 2.0 project, compiling with C# 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, compiler-construction, .net-2.0

I have an old product that I need to update, written in C# and .Net 2.0.  The project has been updated to work with Visual Studio 2010 (which includes the C# 4.0 compiler) but I can not upgrade the framework from 2.0 to any higher version.

I've found multiple articles (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783155/using-extension-methods-with-net-framework-2-0)) that were written around the time of VS 2008, which shipped with the C# 3.0 compiler, stating that you can create your own extension methods by defining your own extension method attribute class for projects that were written with the 2.0 framework.  However, I can not seem to find any reference stating if this is still necessary using C# 4.0 on a .Net 2.0 project.

With my project, will I still need to define the custom extension attribute class or has the C# 4.0 compiler been improved so that it can simplify the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can not seem to find any reference stating if this is still necessary using C# 4.0 on a .Net 2.0 project.

Yes, it is. The compiler needs that attribute. Whether you define it yourself or use the one in `System.Core` is up to you. Though in your particular case `System.Core` is not an option since that is only a part of .NET 3.5.

Once you upgrade to a later version, 3.5 or later, you can safely remove this attribute from your project all together and just use the one in `System.Core`.

If you have upgraded to Visual Studio 2010; then you are using the C# 4.0 compiler. That means all you need is an `ExtensionAttribute`:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

It *must* be in this exact namespace.

Once you've got that somewhere, you can declare an extension method the normal way (since you are using the C# 4.0 compiler):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
    {
        //omitted
    }
}
```

And then use it like an extension method:

```
var str = "hello world";
str.ToTitleCase();
```

You yourself don't actually ever need to put the `ExtensionAttribute` on anything; the C# 4.0 compiler does it for you. Essentially, all the compiler needs is to be able to find an attribute named `ExtensionAttribute`.

Comment: Brr, nasty hack.  Works though.  Upgrading later is going to be a bit painful if he forgets to remove the attribute I imagine.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it'll be catastrophic. The compiler will just pick which ever attribute is "closest". If there is one in the current assembly, it'll use that one instead. I don't think the compiler cares *which* attribute is used; as long as it has the right (full) name. Agreed though, it is a bit ugly.

Comment: Yes, this was something I was hoping to be able to avoid.  The application that I need to update is VERY robust and although it's old, I still need to update it every six months or so and I CAN NOT update the framework due to corporate requirements (err...)  This doesn't seem like to awful of a hack but hacks are something I tend to avoid at all cost in production code.

Comment: @HansPassant: No issues. I use it in IronScheme (as I target .NET 2), but it does not error if I target .NET 4. There is a harmless warning however.